# LOAD DATA IN FILE ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, load-data-infile

SQL says `Error in Line 7`.

Problem in accepting the attributes of the CSV file. 
Thank you in advance for your suggestions and solutions!

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\TO115956\Documents\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\databse\W2.csv'
INTO TABLE W2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(Cde Sap;Num cde cl;Type cde;Bloc livra;Bloc Fact;Org vente;Canal Dist;Sect Act;Don. Ordre;Motif cde;Prix HT;Devise;Terme;Statut_Cde;Date créat;Date creat;Date ACKN;Date PRES;Date RES;Date VAES;Date RFQ;Date VALI;Date REB;RQUO;Date livra;Date SM;Date factu;Avis;PN in;Code chain;Type fab;SN in;Doc Client;Garantie;Livraison;Poste liv;LTA2;VOL2;DATE2;Qté livrée;PN out;SN out;Facture;Montant;Devise)
```

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Sap' at line 7

Comment: I think you have to make double quotes around the names

Comment: I have tried with double qoutes , but it's not working ! @Jens

Comment: MySQL said:  

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Sap' at line 7

Comment: Add the new query and the error message to your question as Update.

Comment: You need to use backticks (`) around your column names if those contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last line of your query should contain database column names. These names should not contain spaces, or dots. (I think they can not actually)

So, you need to change those, to your real column names, not the header from CSV.

Or if your column order matches, you can just remove the last line.

Comment: Hello Fox , I tried this but still not working and neither I can change the Column names of CSV files , it is not possible to do so .

Comment: @AnuraagKapoor What have you tried? What error did you get? Modify your question. There is no need to change anything in the CSV.

Comment: I did the changes in question . I also tried by making Spaceless columns in my database but still it is not working .

Comment: @AnuraagKapoor Show me the query and the error after the modifications. There has to be difference.

Comment: @AnuraagKapoor If it is different from what I proposed, please add your own answer, so that anyone who might google this question up, knows what the correct solution was.